# Using `@unittest.skipIf` with older versions of Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, decorator, backport

With the `unittest` module, I like the [feature to skip tests](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures), but it is only available in Python 2.7+.

For example, consider `test.py`:

```
import unittest
try:
    import proprietary_module
except ImportError:
    proprietary_module = None

class TestProprietary(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.skipIf(proprietary_module is None, "requries proprietary module")
    def test_something_proprietary(self):
        self.assertTrue(proprietary_module is not None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If I try to run a test with an earlier version of Python, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    class TestProprietary(unittest.TestCase):
  File "test.py", line 8, in TestProprietary
    @unittest.skipIf(proprietary_module is None, "requries proprietary module")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'skipIf'
```

Is there a way to "trick" older versions of Python to ignore the unittest decorator, and to skip the test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

unittest2 is a backport of the new features added to the unittest testing framework in Python 2.7. It is tested to run on Python 2.4 - 2.7.

To use unittest2 instead of unittest simply replace
     import unittest 
     with 
     import unittest2

Ref: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2

Comment: unittest2 wasn't satisfactory on my end, although it worked, it spits out a deprecation warning like:
`DeprecationWarning: Use of a TestResult without an addSkip method is deprecated
  self._addSkip(result, skip_why)`
I was unable to get it to disappear quickly.

Answer (score 5):

In general I would recommend not using `unittest` because it has not really a pythonic API.

A good framework for testing in Python is [`nose`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/). You can skip tests by raising a `SkipTest` exception, for example:

```
if (sys.version_info < (2, 6, 0)):
    from nose.plugins.skip import SkipTest
    raise SkipTest
```

This works for Python 2.3+

There are a lot more features in nose:

- You do not need classes. A function could be a test, too.
- Decorator for fixtures (setup, teardown functions).
- Module level fixtures.
- Decorator for expecting an Exception.
- ...

Answer (score 2):

How about using `if` statement?

```
if proprietary_module is None:   
    print "Skipping test since it requires proprietary module"
else:
    def test_something_proprietary(self):
        self.assertTrue(proprietary_module is not None)
```

Comment: Solutions integrated with `unittest` or `nose` will alert the user that a test was skipped. E.g., `Ran 14 tests in 1.325s. OK (SKIP=1)`. The print statement may not satisfy many situations. For example, when using `nosetests`, you'd have to use the `-s` flag to see the print statement.